# How to set up the Azure EventHub to use HTTP or AMQP in .NET client?

Tags: azure, amqp

How to set up the Azure EventHub to use HTTP or AMQP in .NET client? Seems the default AMQP is not working for me and I'd like to try HTTP.

Comment: Can you share the code you have now that's not working?

Comment: So are you stating that the default 'EvenHubClient' makes use of amqp and not http?

Comment: @Zapnologica, yes the official .NET eventhub SDK uses AMQP.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Event Hub REST docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790674.aspx